# iOS 4 GCD questions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I've looked at some of the presentations form WWDC 2010 and also read most of the documents on blocks and concurrency and have a couple of questions regarding using blocks with serial queues in Grand Central Dispatch.
I have an iOS 4 project that has a scrollview and a dictionary of image information - urls to the images and so on. I want to use GCD and blocks to download the images and put them in my scrollview thus not blocking the main thread. I have writen the following code which seems to work:

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in images)
{
     dispatch_async(image_queue, ^{

           NSString* urlString = [dict objectForKey:@"url"];
           NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
           NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
           UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
           UIImageView* imageView = // initialize imageView with image;      

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
           });
           [imageData release];
      });
}
```

I have two questions:

1. According to the concurrency guide I should not capture variables from the enclosing scope that are non scalar types - in my code I capture dict which is an NSDictionary* object. If I am not allowed to capture it, how should I then write the code? Does a block only capture variables from the enclosing scope that are actually used?
2. What happens if I leave the current ViewController before all the images are fetched through the serial dispatch queue? I don't think that they are aware that the ViewController that created them is gone so what happens when they execute the completion handler where I insert the image views into my scrollview on the main thread? Does it cause an error or what? And how can I cancel any remaining operations on the serial queue when my ViewController disappears?

Best regards,

Comment: I'd like to see some best practices on this as well.

Answer (score 10):

1. While it's a niggling point, this is important to understanding what the concurrency guide is trying to tell you: Pointers *are* scalar types. So you can capture pointers inside of blocks all you want... BUT you have to be cognizant of the lifetime of the memory they point to! NSDictionary * is-a-kind-of id, and when you reference an id in a block, the runtime takes responsibility for retaining the id if the block is copied (which it is by dispatch_async()) and then releasing it when the block itself is deallocated. And yes, a block only captures variables that are referenced within it.
2. Since you now know that the async block has done a retain on self, it should be clear(er) that (modulo memory management errors) your ViewController can't "disappear" until the block is done. So it's not going to crash -- but you're correct to note that you really want a way to cancel this kind of async work when you're not actually planning to use the results anymore. One simple-but-effective pattern is to put a test at the beginning of your async block that checks to see if the work should still be done.

Answer (score 3):

Since others have answered your two questions, I would like to comment on your code and recommend you to not use GCD for network queries like images. The main problem with them is that they will all run concurrently. Depending on the number of downloads, you may create way too many simultaneous connections that may bog down a cellular connection, and the user may end up thinking somethings wrong if the images don't start appearing while they are fighting for the *precious* network.

Try to use an `NSOperationQueue` with a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` value of 2 or 3. This will allow you to queue a potentially infinite amount of network requests but have at most a few perform in parallel. Since you can access the network status of the device you can conditionally increase it to say 8 for wifi connections.

And the second problem with GCD, is that it is a little bit cumbersome to cancel pending operations. If your user enters a view controller and then pushes back, depending on how you have programmed your code, GCD blocks will retain the view controller, prevent it from being released, and actually all the network operations will have to finish until the controller can be released (so no point in cancelling the connections in `dealloc`).

I learned this the hard way monitoring a proxy and going quickly inside a view and back. It was really appalling to see how the pending connections *inflicted about 20 seconds of extra network bandwidth damage* to my otherwise unaware application.

tl;dr use a queue for the network, GCD for the image processing/scaling/GUI updating.

Comment: GCD blocks will only run simultaneously if they are dispatched on a global dispatch queue. If you create a serial dispatch queue (a private dispatch queue) then tasks are run sequentially. See [Apple's Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html).

Comment: Sure, the problem is you don't know what `image_queue` is, it could have been assigned to `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)`.

Comment: @Ducan it seems the problem with using a serial queue is then things are totally sequential instead of having the constrained concurrency that maxConcurrentOperationCount allows as Grzegorz said.

Answer (score 1):

@Kaelin Colclasure : for 1st question it seems more likely a problem of shared state in multithreaded application: for integral type you have a copy by value (which applies to pointers also), but when you will use an object referenced by a pointer you'll have all the problems related to absence of locking (kind of variation on object lifetime problem you mentioned here).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the practical difference for your first point:

If I pass a scalar into a block used in a GCD queue, then inside the block I am working with a copy of the original data. Changes will not be visible outside the block. (There are caveats to this, the `__block` modifier for instance but in general this is correct.)

If I pass, say, an `NSMutableDictionary` into a block, changes to the dictionary *will* be visible outside the block -- this is because you retained a *reference* to the dictionary and did not take a deep copy.

In either case memory management is performed for you, that is either the scalar variable is copied or objects are retained.

Since you can't change the contents of an `NSDictionary` after it has been initialised, you'll probably find that blocks automatically do The Right Thing for you.

To the second point, the memory management is pretty much automatic unless you need to work on a copy of a mutable object.

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations and requirements to be aware of when doing BLE development for iOS.
The first involves the iOS Simulator. Interestingly, at one time, the iOS Simulator did support Bluetooth development (the WWDC 2012 Bluetooth 101 video makes a reference to this functionality), but at WWDC 2013, Apple announced that Bluetooth support would no longer be in the Simulator.
On the surface this appears unfortunate. However, developing on a device is a better and more accurate experience with BLE. Additionally, since all iPhones made after the iPhone 4s (2011) have Bluetooth 4.0 — and by extension, BLE — most iOS developers already have devices that support it. We almost don't even need to ask the question anymore, but it's good to know who can use it in case you do have a constrained set of device types for which you're developing apps or BLE devices.

Another important requirement to remember when doing Core Bluetooth development is that Apple places the majority of the responsibility of the interactions with BLE devices on the app developer. Very little is managed and maintained by iOS itself with respect to managing Bluetooth. One thing that's managed in the OS is the connection that appears in the Settings > Bluetooth app.